# Failed to compile ./node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.mjs

Tags: javascript

I want to run my project but there is an error in `@ampproject/remapping`. It was working fine before. I didn't change anything lately. seem it's a version problem.

The error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.mjs
Can't import the named export 'GenMapping' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```